# Return dataframe as class method

Tags: python, class, dataframe

I would like to create report objects that are dataframes when object is created. the code is meant to read a file and do some filtering as part of the instantiation and calling load method

```
class Report:
    def __init__(self,c = ['red','green','blue'],y = [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019]):
        self.color = c
        self.years = y

    def load(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\ger\Desktop\sample.xlsx",sheet_name='sht1')
        df = df.loc[(df['color'].isin(self.color) & 
                     df['year'].isin(self.years)),:]
        return df

# none of these below seems to work though
r1 = Report().load()

# or
r1 = Report()
r1 = r1.load()
```

The expected result would be dataframe with color and year fields as mentioned in init or as defined within the Report() call. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated

Comment: can you share a sample of your excel file? The code works for me if i use a dummy dataframe

Comment: @venky__: the excel file I was using had some issue with it. I used a new file and the code worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is having `load` as an actual class method, here's an example of that working in your case:

```
import pandas as pd

class Report:
    def __init__(self, c=['red', 'green', 'blue'], y=[2017, 2018, 2019]):
        self.color = c
        self.years = y

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple'],
             'year': [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]}
        )
        df = df.loc[df['color'].isin(self.color) & df['year'].isin(self.years)]
        self.df = df
```

In action:

```
>>> report = Report()
>>> Report.load(report)
>>> print(report.df)
   color  year
2  green  2017
```